# How and where to resolve references to other entities in a React / Redux app with normalized state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React / Redux / Immutable and in my state I have stored many `News` objects. Each `News` has multiple `category_ids` assigned. The categories are also stored in (a different sub-tree) of the state. I read in different tutorials, that this kind of normalization is a good thing to have.

So now in the `render()` function of my `News` component I want to display those categories - of course not only the IDs but also the names of the categories.

**components/News.js**

```
renderCategories() {
    const { news } = this.props

    return (
        <CategoryList categories={news.get('category_ids')} />
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderHeadline()}
            {this.renderText()}
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

My `CategoryList` is meant to be a presentational component, so it will only receive props from it's parent and not be `connect`ed to Redux.

So my question is: What is the recommended way to resolve those references to different entitites? Please share your thoughts. If you need more specific infos, please let me know.

Comment: You need to find the parent that shares all the children that needs the categories and connect it to store. This way you will pass them on but you will connect to the store in one parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the place to denormalize data is in a connected component's `mapState` function.  This means that either the parent component would need to map the IDs to the correct items, or it should render a list of connected child components, pass a single item ID as a prop to each child component, and the child component should use that ID to look up its own item and related data.

You may want to read [Querying a Redux Store](https://medium.com/@adamrackis/querying-a-redux-store-37db8c7f3b0f), which discusses ways to denormalize data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is definitely a good read! I will try to build a selector, that is called during `mapStateToProps`. I just have to figure out, how to deal with those immutables in my state. But I guess this points me in the right direction.